# C and C++ library error

Tags: c++, c

I got 3 files (selfdelxp.c, selfdelxp.h and main.cpp)

selfdelxp.c was copied from http://blogorama.nerdworks.in/selfdeletingexecutables/ and I removed the main function as I try to use the `SelfDelete()` function in main.cpp

The problem comes when I try to compile it throwing the error `undefined reference to 'SelfDelete()'`

How can I make it work? What am I doing wrong? What I'm trying to do is to be able to use that function (`SelfDelete()`) in a program written in main.cpp

selfdelxp.c

```
//
//  Self-deleting exe under Windows XP
//
#include <windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

// get this right!
#define EXPLORER_PID 1444

typedef UINT  (WINAPI * WAIT_PROC)(HANDLE, DWORD);  // WaitForSingleObject
typedef BOOL  (WINAPI * CLOSE_PROC)(HANDLE);        // CloseHandle
typedef BOOL  (WINAPI * DELETE_PROC)(LPCTSTR);      // DeleteFile
typedef VOID  (WINAPI * EXIT_PROC)(DWORD);          // ExitProcess

typedef struct
{
    WAIT_PROC   fnWaitForSingleObject;
    CLOSE_PROC  fnCloseHandle;
    DELETE_PROC fnDeleteFile;
    EXIT_PROC   fnExitProcess;

    HANDLE      hProcess;
    TCHAR       szFileName[MAX_PATH];

} INJECT;

#pragma optimize("gsy", off)
#pragma check_stack(off)        // doesn't work :-(

DWORD WINAPI RemoteThread(INJECT *remote)
{
    remote->fnWaitForSingleObject(remote->hProcess, INFINITE);
    remote->fnCloseHandle(remote->hProcess);
    remote->fnDeleteFile(remote->szFileName);
    remote->fnExitProcess(0);

    return 0;
}

#pragma check_stack

HANDLE GetRemoteProcess()
{
    STARTUPINFO         si = { sizeof(si) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

    //return OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, FALSE, EXPLORER_PID);

    if(CreateProcess(0, "explorer.exe", 0, 0, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED|CREATE_NO_WINDOW|IDLE_PRIORITY_CLASS, 0, 0, &si, &pi))
    {
        CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        return pi.hProcess;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}

PVOID GetFunctionAddr(PVOID func)
{
#ifdef _DEBUG

    // get address of function from the JMP <relative> instruction
    DWORD *offset = (BYTE *)func + 1;
    return (PVOID)(*offset + (BYTE *)func + 5);

#else

    return func;

#endif
}

BOOL SelfDelete()
{
    INJECT local, *remote;
    BYTE   *code;
    HMODULE hKernel32;
    HANDLE  hRemoteProcess;
    HANDLE  hCurProc;

    DWORD   dwThreadId;
    HANDLE  hThread = 0;

    char ach[80];

    hRemoteProcess = GetRemoteProcess();

    if(hRemoteProcess == 0)
        return FALSE;

    // Allocate memory in remote process
    code = VirtualAllocEx(hRemoteProcess, 0, sizeof(INJECT) + 128, MEM_RESERVE|MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);

    if(code == 0)
    {
        CloseHandle(hRemoteProcess);
        return FALSE;
    }

    hKernel32 = GetModuleHandle(_T("kernel32.dll"));

    // setup remote structure
    remote = (INJECT *)(code + 128);

    local.fnWaitForSingleObject  = (WAIT_PROC)GetProcAddress(hKernel32,  "WaitForSingleObject");
    local.fnCloseHandle          = (CLOSE_PROC)GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "CloseHandle");
    local.fnExitProcess          = (EXIT_PROC)GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "ExitProcess");

#ifdef UNICODE
    local.fnDeleteFile            = (DELETE_PROC)GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "DeleteFileW");
#else
    local.fnDeleteFile            = (DELETE_PROC)GetProcAddress(hKernel32, "DeleteFileA");
#endif

    // duplicate our own process handle for remote process to wait on
    hCurProc = GetCurrentProcess();
    DuplicateHandle(hCurProc, hCurProc, hRemoteProcess, &local.hProcess, 0, FALSE, DUPLICATE_SAME_ACCESS);

    // find name of current executable
    GetModuleFileName(NULL, local.szFileName, MAX_PATH);

    // write in code to execute, and the remote structure
    WriteProcessMemory(hRemoteProcess, code,    GetFunctionAddr(RemoteThread), 128, 0);
    WriteProcessMemory(hRemoteProcess, remote, &local, sizeof(local), 0);

    wsprintf(ach, "%x %x\n", code, remote);
    OutputDebugString(ach);

    // execute the code in remote process
    hThread = CreateRemoteThread(hRemoteProcess, 0, 0, code, remote, 0, &dwThreadId);

    if(hThread != 0)
    {
        CloseHandle(hThread);
    }

    return TRUE;
}

/*int main(void)
{
    SelfDelete();

    return 0;
}*/
```

selfdelxp.h

```
 #ifndef SELFDELETE_H_ 
 #define SELFDELETE_H_ 

 #include <stdbool.h>
 bool SelfDelete(void);

 #endif // SELFDELETE_H_
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "selfdelxp.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    SelfDelete();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be something like `extern "C" BOOL SelfDelete();` ?

Answer (score 1):

You're getting caught out by C++ name mangling. Note selfdelxp.c is presumably compiled as C code. You need to add extern "C" { ... } around the SelfDelete() deceleration or try compiled selfdelxp.c as cpp (e.g. rename it).

Here is how you would do it with the first approach.

```
#include <windows.h>

extern "C" {
    BOOL SelfDelete();
}
```

(You could also declare that using C++ bool and probably be okay but afik it is better to include windows.h and use the same type)

Comment: In which of these three files should I replace it? I tried on main.cpp and .h and still get error by the compiler

Comment: You need to replace the definition in your header to tell the c++ compiler that the name SelfDelete should not be mangled. Using the above definition you also need to include windows.h prior to the declaration (Just edited the answer to reflect this).

Comment: I didn't see your edit, sorry about that. Anyways, it still doesn't work out

Comment: Assuming you didn't also rename selfdelxp to selfdelxp.cpp in which case you do _not_ need the above, this sounds like the linker isn't being called correctly.

Comment: No, I didn't rename as .cpp. I'm using CodeBlocks on Windows 7 When I try to compile I just compile the main.cpp file assuming that it will link and compile everything properly

Comment: You need to also compile selfdelxp.c and link the two result .o object files.